# get from recursion with exception

Tags: c#, exception, recursion

I have recursive method:

```
private static int F(Tree tree)
```

There is try block:

```
try
{
    ...
    return x;
}
catch (DivideByZeroException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Divide Error");
    throw;
}
```

My question is how to get from rucursion? Becouse if I divide by zero I catch the exception, but still get error. 
Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you remove `throw;` and replace it with `return 0;`?

Answer (score 1):

You throw the exception again in `catch`, if you don't catch it again, then your program will crash which is the intended behaviour in that case.

Is it the same exception that is thrown, or is it the one, you caught in `catch`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the code to be able to continue after the exception, you have to wrap the individual operation that throws the error, and then write code that handles it, e.g. by setting some variable to represent an inferred value. If you have several operations, you must wrap each one. For example:

```
double a;
double b;
try
{
    a = 1000 / 0 ;  //Some operation that computes a, but might divide by zero
}
catch (DivideByZeroException)
{
    a = Double.PositiveInfinity;  //The desired value of a when divide by zero occurs
}
try
{
    b = -1000/0;  //Some operation that computes b, but might divide by zero
}
catch (DivideByZeroException)
{
    b = Double.NegativeInfinity;  //The desired value of b when divide by zero occurs
}
```